# Apple's security measure against using IPhone Camera in Background Mode

Tags: ios

I have a client who wants to create an app that checks for a user's neck posture. I have seen some weird implementations online which aren't very sophisticated so I came up with a way of doing it but I required 1 component which involves facial recognition while the App is in background mode, meaning the user doesn't have the app open and its just running n the background. I've read online Apple does not allow this feature for security reasons and I am wondering is there any possible way to convince Apple to allow me to do this? Are there special cases where we can implement it?

for example

1. The app checks the phone's Pitch position
2. The app checks wether it can detect user's face
3. The app uses these two properties to determine how well the user's neck is aligned with the app.

Comment: You would have to ask Apple, but I suspect that the answer is no. This would involve a significant software engineering change on Apple's part

Comment: I'm quite pleased that security restriction is there.

Comment: Highly unlikely. This isn't just a privacy measure; running the camera (and processing images from it) will use a significant amount of battery power, which isn't appropriate for an application running in the background. That all being said, we have no way of telling you what Apple will say -- if you want to find out, *ask them*.

Comment: I think I get the point guys, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently possible. If you want to convince Apple to change this at some point,

1. Go to http://bugreport.apple.com/ and file an enhancement request
2. Include a highly persuasive argument as to why they should want this in iOS. Be sure to cover the security concerns that prevent it from already being possible.
3. Wait. Probably a long, long time.

Comment: love the enthusiasm in all of your answers .